# Is this NOT considered a proof?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Define the boundary of $A$ as $$Bd(A) = cl(A) \cap cl(X - A).$$

Show that $cl(A) =  int(A) \cup Bd(A)$.

The solution tries to show that $cl(A) \subset cl(A).$I thought I would do it directly,

$int (A) \cup Bd(A) = int(A) \cup (cl(A) \cap cl(X - A)) = [ int(A) \cup cl(A) ] \cap [int(A) \cup cl(X - A)]$

$\implies  = cl(A) \cap X = cl(A).$

Is this not valid?

Comment: try and see if you can prove that $cl(A) \subset int(A)\cup Bd(A)$ and $int(A)\cup Bd(A) \subset cl(A)$

Comment: So I am completely wrong?

Comment: @MillardoPeacecraft, isn't it just $int A \cup (cl(A) \cap cl(X - A) ) \subset int A \cup clA = cl(A).$. The other way is very similar. But i am using the same technique I did before.

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: Which one? Because the solution I read was crazily advanced (kind of)

Comment: Why is $int(A)\cap cl(X-A)=X$?

Comment: @MikeMiller It's not the intersection but the union of the two sets $\text{int}(A)$ and $\text{cl}(X-A)$ that's equal to $X$. In fact, these two sets a re complementary subsets of $X$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Typo, and I know - I just thought that part could probably use a little more justification, since I didn't think it was *immediately* obvious.

Comment: (And thank you for the comment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, your proof is correct assuming $int(A) ∪ cl(X \setminus A) = X$, specially assumming that $X \setminus int(A) = cl(X \setminus A)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good idea to see the whole picture. For each subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ you have a partition of $X$ into three classes of points: those which are in $A$ with some neighborhood (interior points), those which are in $X \setminus A$ with some neighborhood (exterior points) and those for which each neighborhood intersects both $A$ and $X \setminus A$ (boundary points). Let's name those parts as $int(A), ext(A), bd(A)$.

It should be clear that $int(A)$ is the largest open subset of $A$ so it correspond to traditional definition of interior. It should be also clear that $int(A) = ext(X \setminus A)$, $ext(A) = int(X \setminus A)$ and $bd(A) = bd(X \setminus A)$ by the symmetry of the definition.

Now $cl(A)$ is by definition the smallest closed superset of $A$ so by duality of this definition and the definition of $int(A)$ it should be clear that $cl(A) = X \setminus int(X \setminus A) = X \setminus ext(A) = int(A) ∪ bd(A)$ and dually $cl(X \setminus A) = X \setminus int(A) = bd(A) ∪ ext(A) = bd(A) ∪ int(X \setminus A)$.

Finally we can see that $cl(A) ∩ cl(X \setminus A) = bd(A)$ so our definition of border is equivalent to the stadard one.

Comment: Okay, I am not asking for how to do this problem, but I want to verify if I am correct or not in my solution.